# Creating content for iOS/Android app without using PDF

Tags: android, iphone, ios, android-layout, android-intent

I have an app the display list of files and its content on iOS and Android. Currently I use PDF files to show this content on iOS using `iOS-WebView` which worked fine. and now as I'm getting finished with Android application, I have realised that It's hard to get support for pdf files on android specially when you want to display files as a `fragments` on android.

to get pdf files support on android I have tried [MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/), [apv](https://code.google.com/p/apv/), [apdf](https://code.google.com/p/apdfviewer/), [droid-reader](https://code.google.com/p/droidreader/) and  [Android-Pdf](https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library)

and they all either slow, crash with large pdfs or does not support `Fragments in Android`.

I also looked at paid pdf support : [adobe](http://www.adobe.com/),  [qpdf](http://www.qoppa.com/android/pdfsdk/) and  [androidpdf.mobi](http://www.androidpdf.mobi/) which is not feasible for my free app.

So I reached conclusion: to either (1) drop pdf as a content files and use something similar  to show files and it's content on both iOS and Android platform  OR (2) keep looking for way to show pdf under `Android-WebView` using : [Mozilla - pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) like this: [Android-setwebviewclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293373/android-setwebviewclient-setwebchromeclient-displaying-blank-page)  similar to what im doing on `iOS`.

**My Question** : Is there any other way or Tool to generate Design e.g: [this content or document](http://www.rdd-design.com/Kate_margolis_portfolio2.pdf) but without using PDF formate adn distribute them as `.html` files on iOS+Android?

Its really important for me to have drag and drop creation option so the USER of my app who are **not coder** can create best content and distribute on variety of device (which i achieve now using PDF accept it does not have support on Android).

I'm open for all kind suggestion here.